# Plotting a simple histogram in R

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I need to plot a histogram in Rstudio in which I have the values: 1 2 3 4. Their frequency is 0.2 0.5 0.2 0.1 respectively.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways.

## Base R

The function below creates the structure needed to plot a histogram, an object of class `"histogram"`. Then calls the `plot` method for objects of that class.

```
make_hist <- function(x, y, plot = TRUE){
  breaks <- seq(min(x) - 0.5, max(x) + 0.5, by = 1)
  counts <- y*10
  density <- y
  mids <- x
  d <- diff(x)
  equidist <- all(d == d[1])
  h <- list(breaks = breaks,
            counts = counts,
            density = density,
            mids = mids,
            equidist = equidist)
  class(h) <- "histogram"
  if(plot) plot(h)
  invisible(h)
}

make_hist(x, y)
```

[image]

## Package `ggplot2`

With the data set in the question, the best way is to plot a bar plot, with the columns' width equal to `1`, meaning, 100% of the possible width.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df1, aes(x, y)) + geom_col(width = 1)
```

[image]

**Data.**

```
x <- 1:4
y <- scan(text = "0.2 0.5 0.2 0.1")
df1 <- data.frame(x, y)
```

Answer (score 1):

`library(ggplot2)`

```
df <- data.frame(points= c(1,2,3,4), data = c(0.2, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1))
ggplot(df, aes(x = points, y = data)) + geom_histogram(stat = "identity")
```

`ggplot2` is a package that allows for a lot of manipulation with graphs and graphics.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Plot a histogram and write adequate titles
# Main = Title
# ylab & xlab = Axis title
# breaks how many bars you print

hist(sample, main = "Histogram", ylab= "Number of Observation", xlab="Observation's value", breaks = 100 )
```